# Web browser cache clean while javascript development

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2010, caching, browser-cache

I am developing javascript code with visual studio. Everything is working wWhen I run the application first, then I changing some value of javascript variable but browser not showing right result. The old result is appearing.

```
        var validationResult =validate("username");
        var message = "Welcome, ";

        if (validationResult) {
            message += username;
            $("#status").css("color", "green");
        } else {
            message += "Guest";
            $("#status").css("color", "red");
        }
```

In this example, first run on browser shows right result, but I changed the parameter of validate method as "invalidUser" but result did not changed. I thing browser is caching values. Should I clean browser history every run? Is there any clean solution for Internet Explorer or Firefox?

Comment: which browser r u usng?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your browser is caching resources, not values. It could also be your server who is caching.

If you have the firebug plugin/extension in firefox you can disable page caching while developing on a per site basis.

Just install firebug, open it, go to the net tab, click options (little arrow on the tab itself), select disable caches.

http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Thanks Tom. I can use any browser this is not important. Important is solution of my mroblem.

Answer (score 0):

You can force to clean the cache with this javascript

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

with a falase argument will do the opposite